# Поставить лимит на длину массива при добавлении туда элементов

Tags: javascript

У меня есть строки типа ( **Ivan|Ivanov|81234567897|** ) их 50-100шт. Я хочу вводить в тег **textarea** текст типа 812345:10.. То есть номера, в которых 6 цифр совпадают с тем, что я написал в вторую textarea выводить во третью в том кол-ве, которое я задал ( допустим 10, как в примере). Если всего таких номеров 5, а я задал 10, то выводим все 5, а если их 20, а мне нужно 10, то выводить всего 10, оставшиеся оставляем. И совпавшие номера в второй textarea мы их оттуда удаляем и добавляем в третью ( всего три поля: 1 для 812345:10, второе для исходных данных типа Ivan|Ivanov|81234567897|, третье для совпавших Ivan|Ivanov|81234567897| )

Я написал говнокод, так как не смог разобраться с тем, что я написал выше и у меня это выглядит вот так. То есть я использую инпуты, вместо textarea. И собственно сам код... По моей задумке должно выглядеть так https://codepen.io/ohwoow/pen/OJzBMBg

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-format')
const noFormatText = document.querySelector('.no-format-text')
const formatText = document.querySelector('.coincidences-text')
const inputNum1 = document.querySelector('.numbers-1'),
binCount1 = document.querySelector('.bin_count-1'),
inputNum2 = document.querySelector('.numbers-2'),
binCount2 = document.querySelector('.bin_count-2'),
inputNum3 = document.querySelector('.numbers-3'),
binCount3 = document.querySelector('.bin_count-3'),
inputNum4 = document.querySelector('.numbers-4'),
binCount4 = document.querySelector('.bin_count-4'),
inputNum5 = document.querySelector('.numbers-5'),
binCount5 = document.querySelector('.bin_count-5'),
inputNum6 = document.querySelector('.numbers-6'),
binCount6 = document.querySelector('.bin_count-6'),
inputNum7 = document.querySelector('.numbers-7'),
binCount7 = document.querySelector('.bin_count-7'),
inputNum8 = document.querySelector('.numbers-8'),
binCount8 = document.querySelector('.bin_count-8'),
inputNum9 = document.querySelector('.numbers-9'),
binCount9 = document.querySelector('.bin_count-9'),
inputNum10 = document.querySelector('.numbers-10'),
binCount10 = document.querySelector('.bin_count-10');

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

const uncheckedArray = []    
const main = []
const coincidences1 = []
const coincidences2 = []
const coincidences3 = []
const coincidences4 = []
const coincidences5 = []
const coincidences6 = []
const coincidences7 = []
const coincidences8 = []
const coincidences9 = []
const coincidences10 = []
let value = noFormatText.value.split('\n')

for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
  const element = value[i];
  uncheckedArray.push(element.split('|').filter(el => el != ''))
}


for (elem of uncheckedArray) {

 let ccNum = elem[2].slice(0,6)

 if (inputNum1.value == ccNum) {
    coincidences1.push(elem)
 } else if (inputNum2.value == ccNum) {
    coincidences2.push(elem)
 } else if (inputNum3.value == ccNum) {
    coincidences3.push(elem)
 } else if (inputNum4.value == ccNum) {
    coincidences4.push(elem)
 } else if (inputNum5.value == ccNum) {
    coincidences5.push(elem)
 } else if (inputNum6.value == ccNum) {
    coincidences6.push(elem)
 } else if (inputNum7.value == ccNum) {
    coincidences7.push(elem)
 } else if (inputNum8.value == ccNum) {
    coincidences8.push(elem)
 } else if (inputNum9.value == ccNum) {
    coincidences9.push(elem)
 } else if (inputNum10.value == ccNum) {
    coincidences10.push(elem)
} 
}

const coincidencesLimit1 = coincidences1.slice(0, binCount1.value)
const coincidencesLimit2 = coincidences2.slice(0, binCount2.value)
const coincidencesLimit3 = coincidences3.slice(0, binCount3.value)
const coincidencesLimit4 = coincidences4.slice(0, binCount4.value)
const coincidencesLimit5 = coincidences5.slice(0, binCount5.value)
const coincidencesLimit6 = coincidences6.slice(0, binCount6.value)
const coincidencesLimit7 = coincidences7.slice(0, binCount7.value)
const coincidencesLimit8 = coincidences8.slice(0, binCount8.value)
const coincidencesLimit9 = coincidences9.slice(0, binCount9.value)
const coincidencesLimit10 = coincidences10.slice(0, binCount10.value)

if (coincidencesLimit1.length != 0) {
  main.push(coincidencesLimit1)
}
if (coincidencesLimit2.length != 0) {
  main.push(coincidencesLimit2)
}
if (coincidencesLimit3.length != 0) {
  main.push(coincidencesLimit3)
}
if (coincidencesLimit4.length != 0) {
  main.push(coincidencesLimit4)
}
if (coincidencesLimit5.length != 0) {
  main.push(coincidencesLimit5)
}
if (coincidencesLimit6.length != 0) {
  main.push(coincidencesLimit6)
}
if (coincidencesLimit7.length != 0) {
  main.push(coincidencesLimit7)
}
if (coincidencesLimit8.length != 0) {
  main.push(coincidencesLimit8)
}
if (coincidencesLimit9.length != 0) {
  main.push(coincidencesLimit9)
}
if (coincidencesLimit10.length != 0) {
  main.push(coincidencesLimit10)
}

const output = [];

main.forEach(el => {
  for (item of el) {
    output.push(item)
  }
})

function get_user_key(user) {
  return `${user[0]}-${user[1]}-${user[2]}`;
}

let key_by_user = new Map()

for (user of checkArray) {
  let key = get_user_key(user)


  if (!key_by_user.has(key)) {
    key_by_user.set(key, user)
  }

  for (item of output) {

    let itemKey = get_user_key(item)

    if (key_by_user.has(itemKey)) {
      key_by_user.delete(key)
    }
  }
}
noFormatText.value = ''
for (user of key_by_user.values()) {
  noFormatText.value += `|${user.join('|')}|\n`
}

for (item of output) {

  formatText.value += `|${item.join('|')}|\n`

}

})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: давайте еще раз. приведите пример исходного текста, пример "поискового запроса" и пример что в такой ситуации надо получить. не путанное описание что куда вставлять, а конкретные примеры запроса и результата с кратким описанием почему именно так происходит.

Comment: @teran исходный текст состоит из подобных строк Ivan|Ivanov|81234567897|, получить нужно совпадение, которые щас я ввожу в инпуты по 6 цифрам "812345" и их конкретное количество. мой код отрабатывает правильно, но он слишком громоздкий и на 50 строках долго думает.. В примере на кодпене я хочу вводить в поле текст формата 999999:10 6 цифр и количество и искать по ним совпадения в исходном тексте

Comment: @teran если у меня таких строк 100шт Ivan|Ivanov|81234567897| и 6 цифр совпадают с цифрами введеными в поле, то я вывожу допустим 20 штук, а остальные 80 оставляю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потенциально ваш код должен делать что-то такое.

```js
function generateStrings(n = 100) {   
   let result = [];
   
   const rand = function(){
        let x = 1000000000;
        return Math.ceil(Math.random()*(x*10-x) + x);
      };
   
   while(n--){
      result.push( 'Ivan|Ivanov|' + rand() );      
   }
   return result.join("\n");
}

$(function(){
  $("#src").val( generateStrings(5000) );
});

$("#search").click(function(){
   const defaultLimit = 5;
   let searchItems = $("#filter").val().split("\n");
   let result = [];
   
   for (let item of searchItems) {
      let [needle, limit = defaultLimit] = item.split(':');       

      let data = $("#src").val()
                  .split("\n")
                  .filter(function(v){
                      let [name, surname, val] = v.split('|');
                      return val.indexOf(needle)  === 0;
                  });      
     let res = data.splice(0, limit);
     
     console.log(`[${needle}] found: ${data.length}; limit = ${limit}`);
     
     result = result.concat(res);
   }
      
   $("#res").val( result.join("\n") );
});
```

```css
textarea { 
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin: 1rem 0;">
 <textarea id="filter" rows="3">
1:1
2:2
3:3</textarea>
 <button id="search">search</button>
</div>

<div style="display: flex">
  <textarea id="src" rows="10"></textarea>
  <textarea id="res" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы я в textarea смог вписать строчек 10-20 формата 999999:5, 777777:10 и т.д. и он мне бы вывел все совпадение в таком количестве..

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров и чего это сложно было сделать? зы: обновил

Comment: может для вас это было легко, но я не понимал, как ограничить количество совпадений

Comment: спасибо, постараюсь разобраться в вашем коде) так как мне важно понять логику выполнения

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров так ограничение числа совпадений было и до модификации. сейчас только цикл добавил для нескольких значений

Comment: я понимаю, но когда я писал несколько строчек формата 999999:5, то лимит терялся и  я не понимал, как это сделать для каждого элемента ( когда я пытался написать эту логику )